# Spark-Hive Application: SASL Negotiation Failure with Kerberos on a Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, kerberos, apache-spark-2.0

I'm having an issue with a Spark-Hive application running on a Kerberos cluster. I receive a javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed error, which appears to be caused by not finding any Kerberos tgt.

Here's the error log:

```
23/08/04 22:56:55 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
23/08/04 22:56:55 INFO HiveClientImpl: Attempting to login to Kerberos using principal: hdfs@HDP.COM and keytab: hdfs.keytab-2ca1f730-bef7-4166-90ce-67317c75c793
23/08/04 22:56:55 INFO UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user hdfs@HDP.COM using keytab file hdfs.keytab-2ca1f730-bef7-4166-90ce-67317c75c793
23/08/04 22:56:55 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://master3.abc.xyz.com:9083"
23/08/04 22:56:55 ERROR TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
at org.apac...
```

I am submitting my Spark job as follows:

```
spark-submit \
--name TestKerberous \
--num-executors 2 \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./key_fin.conf" \
--driver-java-options "-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./key_fin.conf"\
--files=/etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml \
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.kerberos.principal=HTTP/_HOST@HDP.COM" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./key.conf" \
--conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false \
--conf spark.executorEnv.KRB5_CONFIG=/etc/krb5.conf \
--conf spark.driverEnv.KRB5_CONFIG=/etc/krb5.conf \
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.security.authorization.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.execute.setugi=true" \
--conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false \
--conf spark.home=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/apps/hive/warehouse \
--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive \
--conf spark.yarn.keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.keytab \
--conf spark.yarn.principal=hdfs@HDP.COM \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer  \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 2G --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 2G --supervise \
--class <CLASS_NAME> \
<JAR_FILE>\
"<Hive Jdbc Url>" "thrift://master3.abc.xyz.com:9083" "/apps/hive/warehouse"
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me diagnose what might be going wrong and how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for any insights you can provide